# Trying to delete a whole conversation but struggling with what to parse in the WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `private_messages`, with the following structure:

```
id     message_from     message_to
```

I have a button which once pressed, will delete all the messages concerning the user logged in (`$username`) and the opposing person in the conversation (`$user`).

```
<a href='/inc/delete_conversation.php> Delete Conversation</a>
```

Consider that my `private_messages` table has the following rows:

```
id   message_from    message_to
--   ------------    ----------
1    Alice           conor
2    Alice           conor
3    conor           Alice
4    Anderson        conor
5    Cooper          Alice
```

If I am logged in as `Conor`, I will see `3` messages in the conversation with Alice (2 from her, 1 sent by conor). When I click `Delete Conversation` I want all three of these rows DELETED.

I have a PHP script called `delete_conversation.php`. In this script, I have tried to run the following query:

```
$delete_query = mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM private_messages WHERE 
                                        message_from='$username' 
                                        OR message_to='$username' 
                                        AND 
                                        message_from ='$user' 
                                        OR message_to='$user'
                            ");
```

With the above query, only the logged in users posts are deleted (`$username`). I tried to echo the value of `$user`, the echo returned nothing.

`$user` is the variable which stores what is at the end of the URL. For example, if my URL reads `http://localhost/messages.php?u=Alice`, then the value of `$user` is equal to `Alice`.

The `Delete conversation` link is found on `messages.php`, where the value is appended to the URL. But when the `delete_conversation.php` script is called, it doesn't know what `$user` is.

I thought about using `$_GET`. But I cannot append anything to my anchor link, for example, consider the below:

```
$get_name = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE message_from='$username' OR message_to='$username' AND message_from ='$user' OR message_to='$user'");

$get_all = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_name);
    $mess_from  = $get_all['message_from'];
    $mess_to    = $get_all['message_to'];
    $message_id = $get_all['id'];

    echo "<a href='/inc/delete_conversation.php?id=$mess_from'> Delete Conversation</a>
```

I cannot have an identifier of `$mess_from` or `$mess_to` because that is dependant on who has the latest row in db. For example, if im logged in as conor, I send a message to anderson, `$mess_from` would equal conor.

I am fine with deleting the logged in users posts in the conversation, but struggling to delete the opposite persons messages due to the script not being able to find `$user`.

**Edit**

State's walk through:

- Logged in as freddy.
- Looking through conversation with Alice (at which point, the url reads: `http://localhost/messages.php?u=AliceP`.
  -`delete_conversation.php` currently has the following code in it (nothing else, besides the variable defining code): `echo $username." ". $user;`
- The following results are echo'd - `freddy` - clearly `$user`. has not been found.

Comment: It appears your script is open to SQL injection. You might want to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there are a couple of issues.

---

As far as passing two values in a URI, it's possible to do that. For example:

```
<a href='/inc/delete_conversation.php?mess_from=ann&mess_to=dee'>mytext</a>
```

The values of **mess_from** and **mess_to** would both be available to your script.

---

The SELECT statement shown in the code...

```
 SELECT *
   FROM private_messages
  WHERE message_from = :user_one
     OR message_to   = :user_one
    AND message_from = :user_two
     OR message_to   = :user_two
```

returns an odd result. There are two usernames supplied, but the query is (potentially) returning rows that are related to users *other* than :user_one and :user_two.

There's an order of precedence between AND and OR. Adding parentheses around expressions specifies the order that the terms are to be evaluated.

As a simple demonstration, consider the the following query, and the results returned for the three boolean expressions.

(Note d.f represents message_from, d.t represents message_to)

```
SELECT m.f
     , m.t
     ,   m.f='ann' OR   m.t='ann'   AND   m.f='dee'   OR m.t='dee' AS `_or_and_or_`
     ,   m.f='ann' OR ( m.t='ann'   AND   m.f='dee' ) OR m.t='dee' AS `_or(_and_)or`
     , ( m.f='ann' OR   m.t='ann' ) AND ( m.f='dee'   OR m.t='dee' ) AS `(_or_)and(_or_)`
  FROM ( -- message_from and message_to
         SELECT 'ann' AS f, 'dee' AS t 
         UNION ALL SELECT 'dee', 'ann'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'ann', 'tye'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'tye', 'ann'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'dee', 'tye'
         UNION ALL SELECT 'tye', 'dee'
       ) m
   ORDER BY LEAST(m.f,m.t),GREATEST(m.f,m.t), m.f, m.t
```

The boolean expressions are matching to 'ann' and 'dee'. All of those are identical except for the addition of parens.

A return value of 1 means that the boolean expression evaluates to TRUE, a value of 0 means FALSE.

Compare the results from the boolean expression without parens (the third column) with the return from the expressions with parens (the fourth and fifth columns).

```
f     t     _or_and_or_  _or(_and_)or  (_or_)and(_or_)
----  ----  -----------  ------------  ---------------
ann   dee             1             1                1
dee   ann             1             1                1
ann   tye             1             1                0
tye   ann             0             0                0
dee   tye             0             0                0
tye   dee             1             1                0
```

There's nothing necessarily wrong with rows with 'tye' in the f or t column evaluating to TRUE.  But I suspect that you are only looking to return rows that are related to both 'ann' and 'dee', and not any rows that are part of a conversation with 'tye'.

---

Comment: The issue was pretty much resolved after you said `passing two values in a URI`,but it was great, and worthwhile reading through your explanation. I partially understand the logic you are portraying, and will further read upon it. Nevertheless, thank you for your help Spencer! :)

Comment: The takeway from that long discussion.... AND has a higher precedence than OR. That means  "**a and b or c**" is evaluated as "**(a and b) or c**". If we want a different order, we can specify that using parens...  "**a and (b or c)**".  That's just like in multiplication and addition in arithmetic... multiplication has a higher order of precedence than addition.  With "**a *  b + c**", the multiplication happens first, then the addition. We use parens to specify a different order...  "**a * (b+c)**".

Comment: Get the WHERE clause right on the SELECT, and use the same WHERE clause on the DELETE.  Also, including potentially unsafe values in the SQL text makes the code vulnerable to SQL Injection. The preferred pattern is to use prepared statements with bind placeholders. If you don't do that, then at a minimum, run those values through an appropriate escape function like **mysqli_real_escape_string**. The return value from that function can be incorporated into the text of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

Just use parentheses in your first query:

```
DELETE FROM private_messages
WHERE (message_from = '$username' OR message_to = '$username') AND
      (message_from ='$user' OR message_to = '$user');
```

Or switch to using `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM private_messages
WHERE '$username' IN (message_from, message_to) AND
      '$user' IN (message_from, message_to) ;
```

Big caution:  I am following your original logic, but this will also delete messages to oneself -- if that is allowed.

Also, you should be using parameterized queries rather than plugging values directly in the query string.

Comment: I understand, this however, doesn't quite resolve the issue, although it was probably best for me to lay out my query in this manor. Can you please see my edit? It may provide more light on the issue.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like

```
$delete_query = mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM `private_messages` WHERE 
        ( `message_from`='$username' AND `message_to`='$user' )
            OR
        ( `message_from`='$user' AND `message_to`='$username' )");
```

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that there's an *order of precedence* between the AND and OR operators (one is evaluated before the other)  and that parentheses in a boolean expression specify an order in which expressions are to be evaluated, and that can differ from the order of evaluation when the parens are omitted.